# Using Android phone as a large Microcontroller Kit

Tags: android

I was thinking as a microcontroller kit is nothing(in a way) but collection of processor,lcd,relay..etc and whatever we want it to be, can I use an Android Phone(rooted) as a big ARM processor kit and implement some hardware programming on the device.

If yes, then can someone please guide me to detail tutorials about the procedure.

Thanks.

Comment: How would you plan to find the I/O lines on a PCB with probably 8 layers or more and no schematic available? Most phones are built with BGA packages where you can't even see the pins.

Comment: you can emulate a uc and probably get some ios with a usb to GPIO converter (:P) but you can forget some cool things like real time and low level programming. How difficult is it to grab an ST demo board and start messing with it?

Comment: There is nowhere to plug in a shield/expansion board, no GPIO connectors. Where would you wire up three stepper motors and an extrusion nozzle?

Answer (score 1):

Not really, no - because the hardware is not documented. Most phones are heavily locked down and gaining access to the low-level programming interface requires defeating the manufacturer's security measures.

Comment: even a Rooted phone won't help?

Comment: You need an unlocked bootloader. It's not *impossible*, it's just a huge amount of work. You could start with Cyanogenmod, for example. But this is much more "Linux programming" than "low level / embedded". As others have pointed out, you can't easily add new hardware either.

Comment: well while rooting, my phone's bootloader got unlocked. So the first objective is clear. I want to know how the interfacing of different sensors and cameras in the android is done. Can you point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Try the Android stackexchange.